Tie rendering of Swing column to value in another column
What if the rendering of one Swing table column (its foreground or background, for example) should depend on the value in another column in the same table? How should you design it? Preferably, without

instanceof and casts
bold assumptions and logical dependencies
procedural code (if-elses, switches)

Here's an example of a table that doesn't meet those criteria
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class CustomTableRendererExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom Table Renderer Example");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 400);

            // Create table model with columns "Condition" and "Value"
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Condition", "Value"}, 0);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);

            // Add some sample data
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"High", 100});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"Low", 20});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"Medium", 50});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"High", 80});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"Low", 10});

            // Set custom renderer for the "Value" column
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());

            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    static class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            // Get the value from the "Condition" column (column index 0)
            String condition = table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();

            // Change the background or foreground based on the condition
            if ("High".equals(condition)) {
                c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            } else if ("Low".equals(condition)) {
                c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            } else if ("Medium".equals(condition)) {
                c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }

            // Optionally change the selection colors
            if (isSelected) {
                c.setBackground(c.getBackground().darker());
                c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }

            return c;
        }
    }
}

We have a JTable extension which has a thing called TableRendererInfo that is queried for things like background color of a cell (e.g. info.getBackgroundForCell(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column)). But it's clumsy so I try to research for a better solution (the right one)
It would help if Swing had the concept of a row so that I could set its background, foreground as a whole (and then render individual cells based on their values). But it doesn't

Try using the JTable.setDefaultRenderer method to render based upon a data object. The data class can have properties that can drive your cell render customization.

The code posted in your question colors the value based on the condition.  I don't know how you want the code to look different.  Edit your question to include made-up pseudo code that will color the value based on a condition.  Also, you're not getting away from procedural code,

@prasad_ I'm not sure what you mean. A renderer should render a value. Foreground and background, on the other hand (in my case, I'm really only interested in foreground, though), should be set somewhere higher up. I guess a table extension could perform some pre-render logic that would include querying any foreground/background suppliers. I could include an overloaded addColumn() in that extension that accepts ColorSupplierTableColumns which are TableColumns that implement some ColorSupplier interface (with methods like getForegroundForNeighborCell(), getBackgroundForNeighborCell())

It's quite complex, but what do I do, I need a robust OOP solution

It would help if Swing had the concept of a row so that I could set its background - maybe Table Row Rendering will give you some ideas.

@camickr wow, that's a great idea, thank you. Though, I would still likely need some custom column/renderer extension that supplies colors for other columns
